# spring 2.5 Controllers depreciation?

Tags: spring, controllers

By using Spring 2.5,i have done a leave management project and it was adoptable.But in the reality,many of the controllers and other have been deprecated like "SimpleFormController",
"MultiController" ...so on in the other verion i.e 3.0.Iam little bit in secured ,does they reflect to my project like that.I know at some far,it is secured ,but not sure.suggestion are most welcome and your answers are more help full to me gain confidence.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It is normal that when some library evolves some of its classes can become deprecated. Put your question more clearly what is the problem? Try to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general spring controllers are not deprecated.

There is whole [chapter about Controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-controller) in Spring 4